# Why spreadsheets (like Excel or Google sheets) align text at the bottom of cells?

Tags: tables, alignment

See attached image, cell A3 has default alignment (bottom) and I always find myself changing alignment to the top (like cell B3), because it seems much easier to read to me.

I understand there is a good reason behind that fits most users (I'm not a power user and not working in accounting), but I can't find the answer.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Yes, very annoying. It gives the impression of empty cells when scanning top to bottom. I can only assume this feature was written by a spy for Microsoft to drive customers to Excel. I'll be interested to see convincing answers!

Comment: Indeed, I keep having to realign cells to top to improve readability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because this is the default vertical alignment for tables. You can see the [**Specs for Visual Formatting Model**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align) at W3.org or [Vertical Align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) at MDN

> The following values only have meaning with respect to a parent inline
> element, or to the strut of a parent block container element.
>
> In the following definitions, for inline non-replaced elements, the
> box used for alignment is the box whose height is the 'line-height'
> (containing the box's glyphs and the half-leading on each side, see
> above). For all other elements, the box used for alignment is the
> margin box.
>
> **baseline**
> Align the baseline of the box with the baseline of the parent box. If the box does not have a baseline, align the bottom margin edge with
> the parent's baseline.

[image]

As for WHY was this default chosen, it's because it's easier (or at least it was) to read adjacent content by considering the end of each cell. This comes from old accounting books, see example below, you'll see the amounts are at the baseline of the content of left column (which is multiline).

[image]

However, keep in mind that this behavior is *agent dependant*, meaning that browsers, programming languages and software can declare whichever default they want. For example, Latex aligns to middle and old MS DOS software usually aligned to top

Comment: Thanks for this great answer @Devin! So I understand that it's because spreadsheets' main task is accounting and it makes more sense (thanks for the image). I was asking specifically about Excel and Google Sheets, so I don't think it's related to CSS specifications and implementations, but it's also good context.

Comment: Google Sheets is a web application by definition and Google always standarized their products to W3. Excel probably took the same route based on old accounting books as well. They had to choose one type of alignment, so I guess they chose one that already had some validation (old books or w3). That's why I mentioned MS DOS as well: pre-WWW tables were top aligned, so it seems the Web's cultural impact influenced many GUI decisions